# Duplicate Messagebox in Timer.Tick Function

Tags: vb.net, function, timer, messagebox, duplicates

I am looking for a way to (tell / check) if a (error / warning) MessageBox is still open on another run of a function. an example of what i am asking is:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Class MainWindow
    Dim t As Timer = New Timer

    Public Sub load() Handles Me.Loaded
         t.Interval = 60000

         AddHandler t.Tick, AddressOf tick

         t.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub tick()
         ' if message is not open
         MessageBox.Show("Example Error Message", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
         ' end if 
    End Sub
End Class
```

when the tick event is triggered the if statement checks if the window is open, if it isn't then it shows the message, if it is it does noting

Comment: Doesn't `MessageBox.Show` always display a _modal_ dialog? You can never have more than one.

Comment: In the example which is similar to what I'm working on the messagebox in the tick function creates "Duplicates" of it self showing the same message every time the timer ticks

Comment: My bad. Forgot it was happening within the timer. But that seems like a pretty bad idea, since you have to dismiss the message box before you can do anything in the UI.

Comment: is there any other way you can think of to display a waring without duplicates. any help would be appreciated

Comment: You've two options. Before you show the modal: 1) Remove the handle. 2) Stop the timer. Then, after the modal is closed: 1) Add the handle. 2) Restart the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this;

First declare a global Boolean variable - something like, showError and initialize it to True.

After this I would declare a global MsgBoxResult variable. In this case I called it x. Then I would use this code.

```
Public Sub tick()
     If showError = True then
         showError = False

         x = MessageBox.Show("Example Error Message", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

         If x = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
             showError = True
         End If

     End If 
End Sub
```

The final if statement basically checks to see if the MessageBox has returned a result. This will always be false, until the user clicks OK. Now because the MessageBox only has one button(ok), this if statement will always return True, setting the showError back to True, and therefore making the MessageBox appear again.

Comment: Wouldn't u have to initialize showError to true in order for the event to fire.  EDIT: After i changed showError to true then it worked thanks